# How to configure spring's connection to mysql db for GTM+1

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, timezone

How to configure spring connection to mysql database when I need gtm+1 timezone? I have already UTC and entites are saved for example with 6pm instead of 7pm. It's big problem for me and I didn't find any actual solution with GTM+1.. My connection in application.properties is:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/inzynierka?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

and when I change UTC for GTM or GTM+1 then I'm getting 
java.sql.SQLException: No timezone mapping entry for 'GTM 1'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]

Help me if you have some ideas please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tested this configuration in your persistence.xml?

```xml
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```

You can read more about in this link [How to store date, time, and timestamps in UTC time zone with JDBC and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/).